# Invoking Action when navigating in Google Maps: "[Action Name] is not supported on this device"

Tags: actions-on-google

My action is live.

If I...

- Invoke it (explicit invocation) from the home screen Google Assistant = Great
- Invoke it (explicit invocation) when on Google Maps screen (not navigating) = Great
- Invoke it (explicit invocation) in Google Maps when navigating = "[Action Name] is not supported on this device".

Is there a setting to make it work when Google Maps is navigating?

You can try this with any random Action 3rd party (not Google) in the Assistant with the same effect.

Help!

Comment: Looks like there is a version of Google Assistant that is Navigation Optimized... I guess that means certain actions are not compatible with this?

Comment: Google Maps is probably a "surface" like Android Auto (Actions Console > Deploy > Surface Capabilities). Alas, Google Maps is not listed as a "surface" here...

Answer (score 0):

Actions on Google is not supported in Google Maps.

Comment: Thank you - are App Actions supported on Google Maps?

Comment: Is this forever not supported? or a roadmap item? Looks like App Actions are not supported either in Google Maps nav mode :(

Comment: I can't give an answer to what may happen in the future.