# Triggering Conversational Actions not possible while in Google Maps Navigation Mode

Tags: actions-on-google

While a user is Navigating in Google Maps Nav Mode (Maps is in foreground, talking, etc), Conversational Actions cannot be invoked. Is this a bug? To reproduce, try and invoke any Google Assistant app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking Action when navigating in Google Maps: "\[Action Name\] is not supported on this device"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62940932/invoking-action-when-navigating-in-google-maps-action-name-is-not-supported)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Invoking Action when navigating in Google Maps: “[Action Name] is not supported on this device”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62940932/invoking-action-when-navigating-in-google-maps-action-name-is-not-supported/63287594?noredirect=1#comment111944026_63287594)